# Spring: When to chose which validation method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-rest

I have a Spring application with a JPA Repository.  Now I'd like to add some validations. I found several solutions but none works perfect and I don't know which methode should be used in which case:

1.) Im using validation annotations (e.g. @NotNull) in my model object. But this generates a not usefull rest error response like ""Internal Server Error","message":"Could not commit JPA transaction; "

2.) I'm using the 'Validator' interface for custom validations but I get the spring "compiler" error "Validator has incorrect spelling"

3.) Some tutorials use 'ConstraintValidator' interface

4.) Some tutorials write custom rest methods for validations.

When should I use which and how can I solve my problems?

Comment: What exactly are your problems? You should choose the one that is the least bad for you.

Comment: yep, choose one which is suitable for you. Just like choose framework/tool which you love to work

Comment: In general your object will pass multiple validations. If you have a rest endpoint, you should have validation before calling the repository save method and return a HTTP response. This validation should be doubled by the constraints, to make sure that that is consistent in the database. No worries, in a web application in general you have an additional validation on client side.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can manage it and easy is:

1. Define all your custom message in `/messages/messages.properties` under resources folder.

   so if you error property is: `error.user.name = User name can not be null`.
2. then call your specific property in your pojo for that property.

   ```
    @NotNull(message = "error.user.name")
   ```